# How do you Create an Ethereum wallet in C# directly

Tags: c#, blockchain, ethereum

I have exhausted a number of sources to try and find this answer but simply how do you create a wallet or integrate the `Ethereum Blockchain` in C#?  There are a number of technologies such as `Web3.js`, `MyEtherWallet` (also js) and `Nethereum` which is C# but uses Infura as the API call. There is also a service called `blockcypher.com`

How do you Create an Ethereum wallet that is public to the transfer funds to from one wallet to another? What is the endpoint?

What I am looking to do is programmatically create a wallet for each of my users using my web app and as they earn points I again want to programmatically move funds from my wallet to my user's wallet.

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into [**Nethereum**](https://nethereum.com/) which is an open source .Net integration library for Ethereum...

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example using Nethereum:

```
string password = "MYSTRONGPASS";

EthECKey key = EthECKey.GenerateKey();
byte[] privateKey = key.GetPrivateKeyAsBytes();
string address = key.GetPublicAddress();
var keyStore = new KeyStoreScryptService();

string json = keyStore.EncryptAndGenerateKeyStoreAsJson(
    password: password,
    privateKey: privateKey,
    addresss: address);
```

`json` can be stored in a file. Mist used this file format.

Answer (score 5):

Try Nethereum you can use any rpc end point, not just Infura. This is the same as Web3js, MyEtherWallet, Web3j, etc.

Obviously you will need to have a Node running like Geth, Parity or Besu.

This is an example of transferring Ether in Nethereum's public test chain.

Also you can combine it with @LOST response to encrypt and decrypt your private key using the KeyStore standard.

You can run this sample in the Nethereum Playground http://playground.nethereum.com/csharp/id/1003.

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using Nethereum.Hex.HexConvertors.Extensions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nethereum.Web3;
using Nethereum.Web3.Accounts;

public class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        //First let's create an account with our private key for the account address 
        var privateKey = "0x7580e7fb49df1c861f0050fae31c2224c6aba908e116b8da44ee8cd927b990b0";
        var account = new Account(privateKey);
        Console.WriteLine("Our account: " + account.Address);
        //Now let's create an instance of Web3 using our account pointing to our nethereum testchain
        var web3 = new Web3(account, "http://testchain.nethereum.com:8545");

        // Check the balance of the account we are going to send the Ether
        var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync("0x13f022d72158410433cbd66f5dd8bf6d2d129924");
        Console.WriteLine("Receiver account balance before sending Ether: " + balance.Value + " Wei");
        Console.WriteLine("Receiver account balance before sending Ether: " + Web3.Convert.FromWei(balance.Value) +
                          " Ether");

        // Lets transfer 1.11 Ether
        var transaction = await web3.Eth.GetEtherTransferService()
            .TransferEtherAndWaitForReceiptAsync("0x13f022d72158410433cbd66f5dd8bf6d2d129924", 1.11m);

        balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync("0x13f022d72158410433cbd66f5dd8bf6d2d129924");
        Console.WriteLine("Receiver account balance after sending Ether: " + balance.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Receiver account balance after sending Ether: " + Web3.Convert.FromWei(balance.Value) +
                          " Ether");
    }
}
```

You have many samples of Ethereum wallets using Nethereum, they can be found here http://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/nethereum-ui-wallets/